# Is there any way to know in Servlet is JS is enable or not on browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, servlet-3.0

Is there any way to know in Servlet is JS is enable or not on browser? Also want flash version which installed on browser. I want all this information at Servlet only. We need to log this information at our end.

Comment: You need to send out some piece of Javascript to probe (and send the info back to the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way,

1. Add a new Servlet with some name like `JsServlet`
2. Add a no script tag

   < noscript>

   ```
      < img src="{PATH TO YOUR SERVLET}" >

   < /noscript>
   ```
3. Return some blank image from the Servlet
4. If this Servlet get called you can get that the browser dose not support script.

**Edit** : The servlet code will be,

```
public class JsServlet extends HttpServlet{

  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  /*Write your code that you wan't */
  /*You are here means the browser dose not support javaScript*/

  BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(1, 1,
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  response.setContentType("image/png");
                        OutputStream os =   response.getOutputStream();
                        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
                        os.close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Umesh for your reply. Actually I am try to log user environment when user logs in by adding one filter on login page. But as per you ANS it's totally different call only. Do you have any idea to implement same thing with above scenario?

Comment: @user1041580 - are you saying you want to be able to tell server-side from the first page requested by the user _before_ you return any response?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But yes you can get some information from the request header.

Comment: @Umesh: I have check with header from request, But it didn't that info

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes. I want js enable info before send response.

Comment: It's not possible for the first page a user hits on your site, only from subsequent pages where your first page provides that info in subsequent requests. (The info _may_ be info in the request header from _some_ browsers, but obviously you can't count on that.)

Comment: Not sure, But no I guess, we need something to let server know about the browser.